# Camera and Photo Library together Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

I use the native plugin http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/ to access the **Camera** or **Photo Gallery**.
I need a solution to access the camera and **switch** to the photo gallery if necessary.
Is there such a plug-in or not?

Comment: you can prompt user to choose gallery or camera. But you can't switch.

Answer (score 2):

As Swapnil Patwa says in the comment, you can ask the user with an ActionSheet:

```
public showActionSheet() {
    let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Load from gallery',
        handler: () => {this.loadImage(this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY);}
      },{
        text: 'Take a photo',
        handler: () => {this.loadImage(this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA);}
      },{
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel'
      }]
    });
    actionSheet.present();
  }

  private loadImage(selectedSourceType:number){
    let cameraOptions: CameraOptions = {
      sourceType: selectedSourceType,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      quality: 100,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      correctOrientation: true,
    }
    this.camera.getPicture(cameraOptions).then((imageData) => {
      if(imageData!=null){
        // Do with the image data what you want.
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Now i use actionSheet, but, for example, in the `Viber` app you can select a camera and switch to the photo gallery. I would like to organize this way.

Comment: Camera is a native plugin, I don't think It allows you to do that, in the doc of Ionic 2 I don't find that option.